# SQL Server Report Services Premisson

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder

I am currently looking into developing and designing the Report service system for work.  My user does not seem to have access to Report Builder etc.  I have given access to the below roles, but all  I can seem to do is view report, create new folders and upload.

Browser
Content Manager
My Reports
Publisher
Report Builder

Does anyone know what I need to do to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following [the instructions on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365173.aspx)?

(These are the instructions for SQL 2008- I think the process for SQL 2005 is similar but may differ slightly)